# How to automatically generate a local.properties file with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

For an standard Android project, the local.properties file is by default ignored at .gitignore and it should not be committed at the source code repo but then how to open a new cloned Android project in Android Studio?

Obviously you can manually create a new local.properties file patching the missing piece but common, why to use a full IDE like Android Studio if it cannot open a basic project completing automatically the missing pieces?

Maybe there is a normal standard way to do this (without manually patching a ridiculous file) ... do you know how to do programmatically?

Ironically the original file has a message like "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE" Android Studio will regenerate it automatically but -> HOW ?!?

Answer (score -1):

In your app `build.gradle` file, the app that you have ignored local.properties needs to be recreate, add this method:

```
def createMissingFiles() {
    // Create empty file if not existed
    def propertiesFile = file('src/path/to/your/file/local.properties')
    if (!propertiesFile.exists()) {
        file("src/path/to/your/file/").mkdirs()
        propertiesFile.createNewFile()
    }
}
```

Then call this method inside `android { }` part of the app's `build.gradle` file

```
android {
    signingConfigs {. }
    compileSdkVersion ...
    
    // Let gradle build check and create the missing files for you
    createMissingFiles()

    defaultConfig {.  }
}
```

This method is called on every Gradle build so you can delete the file, click Gradle build button again to test it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tam but if the file is created empty then the whole project will not build for a missing Android SDK path expected at that file ... obviously you can just add the path manually and even with a snippet code like yours but the idea is to make it automatically autodetecting the Android SDK local to each environment

Comment: So I missed the point when you mentioned the default `local.properties` file from the project. This file is supposed to be created automatically after a successful Gradle sync build. No developer needs to create it after cloning a project. If you cannot build your project then the reason is from other issues, not because this file is missing

Comment: Yes, it's other issues but it should be a way to transfer the environment Android SDK configuration to the project automatically since Android Studio already knows this piece of information (if not why to use an IDE called Android Studio if it does not know about the Android SDK) ... but any, if it's not possible to do it automatically I will just path that configuration manually, no worries !!

Comment: I still don't understand why you need to create it manually because Gradle build process already creates this file for you automatically, just like you said, Android Studio knows the information, and it did the job